# CSS reading sliced image into Dreamweaver Div

Tags: html, css, image, dreamweaver

I been learning CSS for a little bit but i have a newb question if i may?

I created a div called footer in my html and i went and used Photoshop to slice a image and save it for web and devices.

I put the html created inside the div and its all over the place, i then put the generated css in the accompanying style sheet which of course puts the image back together just fine but its no longer in the footer div its at the top of the webpage.  Now im assuming i need to put the css inside a specific div for the footer in the css code?  Would this be correct and how should i do this?

Many Thanks

J

Comment: Could you please copy html and/or css fragments here?

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for post your html and css code.

Comment: please provide the code... without code its difficult to trace out the  error...

Answer (score 0):

there is many way to make footer on there correct position u can use `float` `position:fixed` and with`margin-bottem`